# How to use Display() method or any alternative to it?

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have created a program that lets the user create a contact list including name, phone number and b-day into the array. And I have a problem in the `Display()` method, which display the contacts created. Without the `Display()` method, the program only works to where it allows the user to create the contact list. Anybody can help me please? I want to display what is inside the array in an alphabetical order. This is my code below:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace FriendList
{
    class FriendList
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Friend[] list = new Friend[3];
            string name;
            int phone;
            int bDay;
            int i;

            for (i = 1; i < list.Length; ++i)
            {
                GetData(out name, out phone, out bDay);
                list[i] = new Friend(name, phone, bDay);                                              
            }
            Array.Sort(list);
            Console.WriteLine("Sorted Friend's List:");
            for (i = 0; i < list.Length; ++i)            
                Display(list[i]);                         

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void GetData(out string name, out int phone, out int bDay)
        {
            string inString;
            Console.Write("Please enter name: ");
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Please enter phone number: ");
            inString = Console.ReadLine();
            int.TryParse(inString, out phone);
            Console.Write("Please enter b-day(m/d/y)");
            inString = Console.ReadLine();
            int.TryParse(inString, out bDay);
        }
    }

    class Friend : IComparable
    {
        private string name;
        private int phone;
        private int bDay;

        public Friend(string name, int phone, int bDay)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.phone = phone;
            this.bDay = bDay;
        }

        public int Name { get; private set; }

        int IComparable.CompareTo(object o)
        {
            int returnVal;
            Friend temp = (Friend)o;
            if (this.Name > temp.Name)
                returnVal = 1;
            else
                if (this.Name < temp.Name)
                returnVal = -1;
            else returnVal = 0;
            return returnVal;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the implementation of `Display()` ? Also you cannot parse a date formatted like "m/d/y" to int. What are you expecting as parsing result? Storing the phone number as int is a bad idea. If you have a phone number starting with 0 the 0 gets lost while parsing (int does not have leading zeros).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find the implemention of the `Display` method, but I think that what you need is to override the `ToString()` method of the `Friend` class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("Name: {0}; Phone: {1}; BirthDay: {2}", name, phone, bDay);
}
```

and then print the content with `Console.WriteLine`:

```
for (i = 0; i < list.Length; ++i)
{
    Console.WriteLine(list[i]); //same as Console.WriteLine(list[i].ToString())
}
```

Later edit

About the alphabetical sort, the `IComparable.CompareTo` method is not working because you compare the Auto-implemented property `Name` that doesn't have any reference to the `name` variable that contains the name of the `Friend`. You can do 3 things:

1. Change the variable used for comparison in `IComparable.CompareTo`from the property `Name` to `name`;
2. Implement the property `Name` as following:

   ```
   public string Name 
   {
      get { return name; }
      private set { name = value; }
   }
   ```
3. Use the auto-implemented property `Name` and forget about the 'name' variable:

   ```
   public Friend(string name, int phone, int bDay)
   {
       this.Name= name;
       this.phone = phone;
       this.bDay = bDay;
   }
   public string Name { get; private set; }
   ```

Another thing is that you use the Name property as an int, but it should contain a string. You may want to change the `IComparable.CompareTo` method with something like this to compare two strings:

```
    int IComparable.CompareTo(object o)
    {
        int returnVal;
        Friend temp = (Friend)o;
        returnVal = this.Name.CompareTo(temp.name);
        return returnVal;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This works but the output is not sorted alphabetically.

Comment: To sort, you could use linq `OrderBy` instead of implement IComparable

Comment: @GabrielIoniță That's why I was wondering why IComparable.CompareTo is not working! Thank you so much for the help! I was stuck with this the whole time. It is good to have someone correct you. Thank you so much again!